# Alternative to ping for determining healthy machines

Tags: architecture, distributed, distributed-system, health-monitoring

Our uber-service consists of multiple services running on separate machines. To ensure that the services are healthy and reachable, other machines will periodically send a "ping" request to the services. Determining timeout for the ping is tricky, we don't want to wait too long (fail-fast approach), but we don't want to fail too quickly as well (since when load is high, pings can get queued on the receiving server and time outs can happen which can lead to failovers causing a cascade). We have also identified that pings can clog the network.
I was wondering if there is an alternative to the ping (possibly keeping an open TCP connection?) that is better at identifying the scenario of machine becoming unhealthy/unreachable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gossip protocols can significantly reduce your health traffic, and they converge pretty quickly.

Could you build a health system on top of gossip?

As an alternative, your Service hosts could send heartbeats to a central service, and that Service could be the standard of system health. Zookeeper ephemeral entries could fit the bill, or a similar system.